# ¿Por que Github solo muestra el ReadMe?

Tags: javascript, html, css3, github, github-pages

A ver si me doy a entender, resulta que hice una página web simple que me funciona perfectamente en mi localhost, pero cuando lo quiero subir en github lo único que sale es el ReadMe y no aparece ni el html, ni el css, ni el javascript y ese problema me tiene un poco confundido ya que es la primera vez que me pasa algo así ¿ alguien me ayuda?

Código html

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>diceGame</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="fav/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dela+Gothic+One&family=Inconsolata&family=Righteous&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="text">
            <h1>Refresh Me</h1>
    
            <div class="player">
                <div class="player" id="player1">
                    <p>Player 1</p>
    
                </div>
    
                <div class="player" id="player2">
                    <p>Player 2</p>
    
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
    
        <div class="Contenedor">
            <div class="dice" id="dice1">
                <img src="images/dice6.png" alt="dice6">
            </div>
            <div class="dice" id="dice2">
                <img src="images/dice6.png" alt="dice6">
            </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Código CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #222831;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.dice {
  float: left;
}
#dice1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 380px;
}
#dice2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 90px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #16c79a;
  font-family: "Righteous", serif;
  font-size: 80px;
}

p {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  float: left;
}
.player {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Inconsolata", serif;
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#player1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 80px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #16c79a;
}
#player2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 90px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #16c79a;
}
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Código JavaScript

```
[![var randomNumber1;
randomNumber1 = Math.random();
randomNumber1 = randomNumber1 * 6;
randomNumber1 = Math.floor(randomNumber1) + 1;
console.log(randomNumber1);

function cambiarImagenes() {
  let img1 = (document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[0\].src = "images/dice1.png");
  let img11 = (document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[(0, 1)\].src =
    "images/dice1.png");
  let img2 = (document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[0\].src = "images/dice2.png");
  let img22 = (document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[(0, 1)\].src =
    "images/dice2.png");
  let img3 = (document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[0\].src = "images/dice3.png");
  let img33 = (document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[(0, 1)\].src =
    "images/dice3.png");
  let img4 = (document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[0\].src = "images/dice4.png");
  let img44 = (document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[(0, 1)\].src =
    "images/dice4.png");
  let img5 = (document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[0\].src = "images/dice5.png");
  let img55 = (document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[(0, 1)\].src =
    "images/dice5.png");
  let img6 = (document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[0\].src = "images/dice6.png");
  let img66 = (document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[(0, 1)\].src =
    "images/dice6.png");

  if (randomNumber1 === 1) {
    img1 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[0\].src = "images/dice6.png";
    img11 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[(0, 1)\].src =
      "images/dice3.png";
    if (img1 > img11) {
      var text = document.querySelector("h1");
      text.innerHTML = "Player 1 wins!!!";
    } else if (img1 < img11) {
      var text = document.querySelector("h1");
      text.innerHTML = "Player 2 wins!!!";
    }
    if (img1 === img11) {
      var text = document.querySelector("h1");
      text.innerHTML = "Draw!!!";
    }
  }
  if (randomNumber1 === 2) {
    img2 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[0\].src = "images/dice3.png";
    img22 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[(0, 1)\].src =
      "images/dice1.png";
      if (img2 > img22) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Player 1 wins!!!";
      } else if (img2 < img22) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Player 2 wins!!!";
      }
      if (img2 === img22) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Draw!!!";
      }
  }
  if (randomNumber1 === 3) {
    img3 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[0\].src = "images/dice1.png";
    img33 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[(0, 1)\].src =
      "images/dice5.png";
      if (img3 > img33) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Player 1 wins!!!";
      } else if (img3 < img33) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Player 2 wins!!!";
      }
      if (img3 === img33) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Draw!!!";
      }
  }
  if (randomNumber1 === 4) {
    img4 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[0\].src = "images/dice5.png";
    img44 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[(0, 1)\].src =
      "images/dice2.png";
      if (img4 > img44) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Player 1 wins!!!";
      } else if (img4 < img44) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Player 2 wins!!!";
      }
      if (img4 === img44) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Draw!!!";
      }
  }
  if (randomNumber1 === 5) {
    img5 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[0\].src = "images/dice2.png";
    img55 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[(0, 1)\].src =
      "images/dice6.png";
      if (img5 > img55) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Player 1 wins!!!";
      } else if (img5 < img55) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Player 2 wins!!!";
      }
      if (img5 === img55) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Draw!!!";
      }
  }
  if (randomNumber1 === 6) {
    img6 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[0\].src = "images/dice1.png";
    img66 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")\[(0, 1)\].src =
      "images/dice4.png";
      if (img6 > img66) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Player 1 wins!!!";
      } else if (img6 < img66) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Player 2 wins!!!";
      }
      if (img6 === img66) {
        var text = document.querySelector("h1");
        text.innerHTML = "Draw!!!";
      }
  }
}
cambiarImagenes();][1]][1]
```

Esta imagen muestra como se ve en el local host

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, miren como esta imagen nisiquiera muestra el html de la página, parace ser que por una extraña razón el github solo me esta leyendo el readme y no entiendo el porque de ese error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Conectate a https://ricardo120399.github.io/DiceGame/diceGame/

Comment: Gracias viejo, funciona pero ¿cómo lo solucionaste? me gustaría saberlo para una próxima ocasión, muchas gracias.

Comment: Vi en la última imagen que habías pegado cuál era la URL. Probé a conectar y efectivamente vi solo el README. Entonces usé tu id de usuario (visible en la URL) para entrar al repositorio en github y ver su estructura de carpetas. Ahi vi que en la raiz tenías solo el README, mientras que el index.html estaba en una subcarpeta llamada `diceGame`, así que probé añadiendo el nombre de esa carpeta a la ruta. Y bingo!